# Debian static ip, can not bring up interface: "RTNETLINK answers: File exists"

Tags: networking, linux-networking, internet, debian-stretch

I have a fresh installation of SELKS(Debian 9) and I configured the network manually, but I can not bring the interface `eno1` UP.

I get the error:

```
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
ifup: failed to bring up eno1
```

My `/etc/network/interface` configuration is the following:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eno1
iface eno1 inet static
    address 192.168.200.32/24
    gateway 192.168.200.1
    # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

which was auto generated by Debian setup when I clicked configure network manually, at the installer, so I am guessing it is correct.

Also I noticed that the `/var/run/network/ifstate` file does not include `eno1`, and that the `ifstate.eno1` file is empty:

```
root@user:/home/user# cat /var/run/network/ifstate
lo=lo
root@user:/home/user# ls /var/run/network/
ifstate  ifstate.eno1  ifstate.lo
root@user:/home/user# cat /var/run/network/ifstate.eno1 

root@user:/home/user#
```

Even if I try to enter manually the value `eno1=eno1` still the interface can not be brought up.

I tried bringing the interface down and then up, as well as flushing the interface( `ip addr flush dev eno1`) but the results are the same:

```
root@user:/home/user# ifdown eno1
ifdown: interface eno1 not configured

root@user:/home/user# ifup -vvv eno1

ifup: configuring interface eno1=eno1 (inet)
/bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ethtool
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wireless-tools
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant
/bin/ip addr add 192.168.200.32/255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.200.255       dev eno1 label eno1
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
ifup: failed to bring up eno1

root@user:/home/user# ip addr flush dev eno1
root@user:/home/user# ifup eno1
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
ifup: failed to bring up eno1
```

Also, here are the outputs of `ethtool -i` and `dmseg`:

```
root@user:/home/user# ethtool -i eno1
driver: bnx2
version: 2.2.6
firmware-version: 6.2.12 bc 5.2.3 NCSI 2.0.11
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: 0000:02:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no

root@user:/home/user# dmesg | grep -i eth
[    1.801411] bnx2: QLogic bnx2 Gigabit Ethernet Driver v2.2.6 (January 29, 2014)
[    1.802139] bnx2 0000:02:00.0 eth0: Broadcom NetXtreme II BCM5716 1000Base-T (C0) PCI Express found at mem da000000, IRQ 16, node addr bc:30:5b:d9:17:72
[    1.802971] bnx2 0000:02:00.1 eth1: Broadcom NetXtreme II BCM5716 1000Base-T (C0) PCI Express found at mem dc000000, IRQ 17, node addr bc:30:5b:d9:17:73
[    1.830740] bnx2 0000:02:00.0 eno1: renamed from eth0
[    1.849481] bnx2 0000:02:00.1 eno2: renamed from eth1
[    6.694317] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.PMI0._GHL] (Node ffff9202369ae460), AE_NOT_EXIST (20160831/psparse-543)
[    6.694558] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.PMI0._PMC] (Node ffff9202369aee38), AE_NOT_EXIST (20160831/psparse-543)
```

I tried almost everything suggested here for this topic, but still could not find any answer.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've assigned the ip address manually earlier, and when you tried to bring up interfaces, the address assignment failed.

Likely the second error has been caused by manual edit of the `/var/run/network/ifstate.eno1` file. Don't do it!

At result, the correct steps:

- `ifdown --force -vvv <iface>`
- `ip address flush dev <iface>`
- `ip link set <iface> down`
- `ifup -vvv <iface>`

Comment: Hey mate. Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately `ifdown` did not work even with  `--force` option. Here is the output:

```root@user:/home/user# ifdown --force -vvv eno1

ifdown: configuring interface eno1=eno1 (inet)

/bin/run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-down.d

run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-down.d/upstart

run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-down.d/wpasupplicant
 /bin/ip route del default via 192.168.200.1 dev eno1 2>&1 1>/dev/null || true
 RTNETLINK answers: No such process```

I had to break the comment into two so the next is one is the rest of the command output

Comment: ```/bin/ip addr del 192.168.200.32/255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.200.255 dev eno1 label eno1
 /bin/ip link set dev eno1 down
 /bin/run-parts --verbose /etec/network/if-post-down.d
 run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-post-down.d/wireless-tools
 run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-post-down.d/wpasupplicant```

Comment: Seems like good for your case. Don't mind of  the `ifdown` alerts messages if you're running it with `--force` option. Just run the next commands. Also you can try to comment the `gateway` option under the `eno1` interface section in the `interfaces` file. Easy way is just reboot the system.

Comment: Hey mate. I tried all the command in the order you gave me, but still the last ```ifup -vvv eno1``` produces the same RTNETLINK error
Should I try the ifdown command with `--force` and then reboot the system?

Comment: If you will reboot the system, you don't need run the `ifdown` command anyway.

Comment: Do you mean reboot the system and then check if the interface is up? If that's the case, I tried that as well, but still it appears as down, and I can not bring it up

Comment: After reboot the interface should brought up automatically because you have `allow-hotplug` option.

Comment: Hey mate. I tried restarting and the interface still is down.
The RTNETLINK displays the same message. Do you have any other suggestion that I could try?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Comment the `allow-hotplug` and `gateway` and `dns` options. Check the Network Manager service. Reboot. Then try `ifup --vvv eno1` command and share the output.

Comment: Hey mate sorry for the delay. I tried but still the same errors appears: `RTNETLINK answers: File exists
ifup: failed to bring up eno1`

Comment: Have you check the state of interface and address before trying to bring up the interface?

Comment: You mean running `ip link sh` and `ip addr sh` , correct?

Comment: Yes, sure. Check it.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply mate. After lots of testing I fixed it!
I tried everything you mentioned, plus a firmware updates on the NICs, and it worked. Thank you SO much for your help and your patience. Cheers!